# jQuery and ASP.NET textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

 $(document).ready(
 function () {

     $("input[id$='txt_ClientIntakeDate']").val("Text From Jquery");

     $("input[id$='txt_ClientIntakeDate']").datepicker();

 }

 );
```

I added the above code in the asp.net  page which contains master page. The first statement is working and display the text in the text box. and the second statement is displaying error"Object doesn't support this property or value". I added both jQuery and jQuery UI reference. I run it in IE  and firefox. Do you have any idea about this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery UI library isn't getting included correctly, double check that `<script>` tag.  For instance, in Firefox view source and click on the link in that tag (it turns the `src` into a link), does it come up?

- If not, fix your reference locally or [include it from a CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI).
- If your `src` *is* valid, make sure you're not including jQuery core **again** in the page, which will overwrite any plugins, including jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$("input[name*='<%=txtDate.ClientID%>']").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true

        });
```

I guess you are missing **name***